# Find $||\vec{w}||$ where $ ||\vec{u}|| = ||\vec{v}|| = 1$, $\vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w} = 0$, and $\vec{u} \perp \vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I was requested to find $||\vec{w}||$ where $i) \space \space ||\vec{u}|| = ||\vec{v}|| = 1$, $ii) \space \space \vec{u} + \vec{v} + \vec{w} = 0$, and $iii) \space \space \vec{u} \perp \vec{v}$. I am very new to multivariate calculus and was wondering if my solution is correct. Here is what I attempted.

$I$. From $ii$ it follows that $\vec{u} + \vec{v} = -\vec{w}$. It is clear from the definition of a norm that that $||\vec{w}|| = ||-\vec{w}||$, since negative components are squared and hence always become positive. Therefore, $||w|| = ||\vec{u} + \vec{v}||$.

$II$. $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ can be thought of as the diagonal of the parallelogram with sides $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. Because $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ have equal lengths $(i)$ and are orthogonal $(iii)$, such paralellogram is a square. Therefore $\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ is the diagonal of a square with sides of length $1$ $(i)$.

$III$. From $II$ it follows that, by application of Pythagoras theorem, $||\vec{u} + \vec{v}|| = \sqrt{||\vec{u}||^2 + ||\vec{v}||^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt{2}$. From $I$ we have $||\vec{u} + \vec{v}|| = ||w||$. Therefore, $||||\vec{w}|| = \sqrt{2}$.

I am aware that this may be a simple problem. However, I am only starting to build a basic understanding of multivariate calculus, and since I self study I don't have teachers to tell me whether my solutions are right or wrong (specially in problems that involve demonstrations rather than mere calculations).

I would highly appreciate $a)$ validation/correction of my proof, and $b)$ alternative proofs or ways to solve the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks correct to me!

Comment: "Since negative components are squared" is not quite right, but it's probably just terminology. You're right that $||-w|| = ||w||$ always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would highly appreciate $a)$ validation/correction of my proof, and
> $b)$ alternative proofs or ways to solve the problem. Thanks in
> advance!

a) You proof seems fine

b) Another way of solving this is to use the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties)

As you stated in your answer, you can write
$$-\vec{w}=\vec{v}+\vec{u}$$

Now, using the dot product properties, we have

$$||\vec{w}||²= \vec{w}.\vec{w} = (-\vec{w}).(-\vec{w}) $$

Combining the previous results, you can get
$$||\vec{w}||² = (\vec{u}+\vec{v}).(\vec{u}+\vec{v})$$

Since the dot product is distributive and commutative, this means that:

$$||\vec{w}||² = (\vec{u}.\vec{u})+ (\vec{v}.\vec{v}) + 2 \times (\vec{u}.\vec{v}) = ||\vec{u}||² + ||\vec{v}||² + 2 \times (\vec{u}.\vec{v}) $$

Now, by definition: $$\vec{u}\perp\vec{v} \iff \vec{u}.\vec{v} = 0$$

So:

$$||\vec{w}||² = ||\vec{u}||² + ||\vec{v}||² = 1 + 1 = 2 $$

And since a norm is always positive, $$||\vec{w}|| = \sqrt{2}$$